# Получить посты с картинками

Tags: wordpress

Получаю нужные посты с помощью следующего кода:

```
$args = [
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'post_type' => 'page'
];
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
...
```

А возможно ли на Wordpress получать только те посты, у которых есть хотя бы одно изображение (есть `attachment` с типом `image/jpeg`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не получится. Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду. Тут два варианта, и оба не работают.

1. Если вы имеете ввиду изображения внутри записи - их никак не вытащить через `WP_Query`. Только разбирать html в `$post->post_content`.
2. Если вы имеете ввиду изображения, прикреплённые к посту, то их можно вытащить через метаполя с помощью `WP_Query`. Но запрос вам не вернёт информацию о типе вложения (`image/jpeg`)

Всё, что вы можете сделать - поставить `posts_per_page => -1` и разбираться с изображениями в цикле. Как только получили первые 8 с нужного типа картинками, прекращайте цикл. Очевидно, что такой подход далеко не оптимален.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, я имел ввиду изображение записи (миниатюру). Значит всё таки придётся использовать костыль с posts_per_page => -1 и перебором цикла. К счастью, постов с нужным мне типом не так много, поэтому на производительности страницы это практически не скажется.

Comment: Скажется, если у вас много постов вообще. Потому что -1 заберет ВСЕ посты в один запрос ((

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Дело в том, что нужных мне ТИПОВ постов - около 30 штук, поэтому для меня такой костыль вполне приемлим. Если бы таких постов было бы больше, тогда да, с posts_per_page => -1 были бы проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из возможных решений:

```
$args = [
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'needed_post_type' //нужный тип поста
];
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if($loop->have_posts()) {
    $counter = 0;
    while($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            the_post_thumbnail('full');
            $counter++;
            if($counter == 8) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: код нормальный, но вы тут никак не анализируете тип изображения

Comment: Можно использовать https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_attachment_metadata